# How to understand "...to hide the evidence of mishandled magic, or else hidden by castle-proud house-elves" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> There were alleyways and roads bordered by teetering piles of broken and damaged furniture, **stowed away, perhaps, to hide the evidence of mishandled magic, or else hidden by castle-proud house-elves**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince</sub>

I have some difficulty understanding the part in bold. It seems to me that it's saying *the broken and damaged furniture was stowed away to hide the evidence of mishandled magic and if it's not done so, the castle-proud house-elves would hide mishandled magic.* Is that what it's saying? Does 'castle-proud house-elves' mean the house-elves who are proud of the castle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is offering two quite different possible reasons for the piles of furniture:

1. Stowed away to hide the evidence of mishandled magic

or

2. Hidden by castle-proud house-elves.

*Castle-proud* is not a common expression, but it is a deliberate variant on the idiom *house-proud*. It implies that the house-elves like their castles to look their best, so have hidden away furniture that is broken.

Comment: castle-proud is not an expression. It is merely literary writing.

Comment: The words "stowed away" are also part of the first option. The two past participles "stowed" and "hidden" are the main components of the parallel sentence structure.

Comment: You're right @aschepler: I missed that. I've edited it.